# Does python takes enter as an input?

Tags: python, output

I executed a program to input n space-separated integers as input, create a tuple, and the use hash() on them.

```
print(hash(tuple(map(int, input().split(" ")))))
```

I am using Pycharm IDLE.
 While execution after entering the numbers and pressing I get the answer in one line in the following code:

```
print(input()==0 or hash(tuple(map(int,input().split()))))
```

But After I press enter in the following code, the pointer moves to the new line and then I have to press enter again.

My question is :
1) Why do I have to press enter twice in the second one.
2) Does Python takes enter as an input or as a null input.

A dry run would be clarify a lot of my doubts.

Comment: Because you have two calls to `input()` in the second one?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just a typo @DavyM.

Comment: You're calling `input()` twice. Each time you call it, it reads another line, which of course requires another Enter key. If you want to use the same input twice, store it in a variable in one statement (`line = input()`), and then use that variable (`line`) in the expressions in the next statement.

Comment: Also, `input()` is never going to equal `0`. It may be an empty string, or it may be the string `'0'`, but it's not going to be the number 0. And, given both your problem statement and the other half of your expression, it's more likely to be something like the string `'1 0 2 5 3'` or something, so… what were you trying to test here?

Comment: Finally, what made you think that writing this all in a single line of code was a requirement, or even a good thing? If an expression statement is too complicated for you to understand (and if you have to come to StackOverflow for help, it is), break it up into separate statements.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, the reason you're having to press enter twice when running the code

```
print(input()==0 or hash(tuple(map(int,input().split()))))
```

is simply because you're calling the `input` function twice. This behavior can be reproduced with a simple example

```
>>> input(), input()
pressed enter once
pressed enter twice
('pressed enter once', 'pressed enter twice')
>>>
```

Since you only want to ask the user for input once, you need to save the result of the first call to `input` in a variable:

```
>>> var = input(); print(var == 0 or hash(tuple(map(int, var.split()))))

3527539
>>>
```

Also, as others have already said, I'm not really sure why you tried to write your code all on one line. Yes writing concise code is not a bad goal, so long as that code remains readable. Often times it's simply better (and in your case, necessary) to divide you code among multiple lines.

Comment: I have not saved the input() anywhere and I have asked for input twice and still I am getting the correct output. Why? If I am right , python works from left to right so the first time input() is executed I enter an output and the statement goes to or. After that I do not enter any input then how do I get the output?

Comment: Actually @SachinMatta, your code only appears to be working. Your code produce the correct result for an empty string, but since you are calling `input` twice, you're using to different values. Even when the user enters different values, your code will always produce the same result. When running your original code, try entering several random numbers for the first input prompt, and then press enter twice. You'll discover the same value - `3527539` is returned each time.

Comment: But why is it producing the same result? During the first input() , the input is not being stored. so in memory there is no value. All the operations are being operated on the input from the second input().